# Unable to send mail to hMailServer with 554 error

Tags: hmailserver

It is unable to send mail to hMailServer with error `554 Your message was received but it could not be saved. Please retry later`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the disk space of device (e.g. Windows Server) which installed the hMailServer.
If it is 0 bytes free, the mail cannot be delivered as a result.